# what's differences and relation with SOAP and Restfull

Tags: java, rest, rpc

what's differences Bwtween SOAP and Restfull? What's more, which topic application or program belong to SOAP? what's the key indicator for the differences. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find answer in many web page by simple search such as `SOAP vs Restful`.

Comment: Your question can duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296116/how-do-restful-and-soap-web-services-differ-in-practice too

Comment: Many thanks, what's more, if webdav method is restfull?

Comment: I don't understand your means.

Comment: FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

Comment: I think don't exist any problem between `Restful` and `WebDAV protocol`. See following urls: * http://wiki.exoplatform.org/xwiki/bin/view/JCR/WebDav * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745015/webdav-troubles-for-restfull-wcf-web-service * https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Jersey+WebDAV+Support+-+Interop

Comment: I recommend you to read this documentation to learn how REST is used in Java, it might be pretty helpful for you to understand the differences: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP is a particular technology for implementing client / server systems that is based on XML and HTTP.

RESTful is a set of design rules / guidelines for implement web-based services.

Comment: Strictly speaking, REST in its purest sense doesn't have anything to do with the web. It's just that it's almost always associated with the web and HTTP as its underlying application protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are the key element of a true RESTful design, as opposed to "methods" or "services" used in RPC and SOAP Web Services, respectively.